# Displaying a hierarchical tree with Baum in Laravel / Recursive functions in laravel

Tags: recursion, laravel, laravel-4, tree, hierarchy

So I've just installed the Baum package in Laravel and put together a small tree of categories.

I've been able to display the tree in nested JSON format with the getDependentsAndSelf() method, but I have no idea how to go about actually displaying this in a usuable format with laravel.

Ideally I'd just like to spew them out in an indented list format, but I feel like that would probably require some recursion and I have no idea how to do that in Laravel.

Here's the output I have right now:

```
 {"14":{"id":14,"parent_id":null,"name":"Root","lft":1,"rgt":6,"depth":0,"children":[{"id":15,"parent_id":14,"name":"Child 1","lft":2,"rgt":5,"depth":1,"children":[{"id":16,"parent_id":15,"name":"Child 2","lft":3,"rgt":4,"depth":2,"children":[]}]}]}}
```

Essentially it's just a tree of the format

```
- Root
    - Child 1
        - Child 2
```

So what's the best way to go about this in laravel? In php I could have just made a function that recursed upon itself, but I'm not sure how to do that in my laravel view.

Comment: Did you figure this out eventually?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm sure it's possible, I'm just so new to Laravel and MVC platforms that I don't quite understand how I'm supposed to deal with the logical side of things now.

Answer (score 6):

You can use method described here: https://gist.github.com/etrepat/6920301

```
<?php

$roots = Category::roots()->get();

echo "<ul>";
foreach($roots as $root) renderNode($root);
echo "</ul>";

// *Very simple* recursive rendering function
function renderNode($node) {
  echo "<li>";
  echo "<b>{$node->name}</b>";

  if ( $node->children()->count() > 0 ) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($node->children as $child) renderNode($child);
    echo "</ul>";
  }

  echo "</li>";

}
```